# Google InApp Billing Null Exception

Tags: android, in-app-billing, google-play-services

I am getting a Null Exception error when I query the Product listing for a Google InApp Billing item.

I have one item added to the In-App Developer Console website and it shows the status as "Active";

Below is my code.

```
 // Listener that's called when we finish querying the items and subscriptions we own
IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener mGotInventoryListener = new IabHelper.QueryInventoryFinishedListener() {
    public void onQueryInventoryFinished(IabResult result, Inventory inventory) {
        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory finished 15.");
        if (result.isFailure()) {
           Log.d(TAG,"Failed to query inventory: " + result);
            return;
        }

        SkuDetails productDetails = inventory.getSkuDetails(SKU_ANATVITALSIGNS);

  //      Log.d(TAG,"Gas Price is: " + productDetails.getPrice());

        if (productDetails != null){
            Log.d(TAG,"Deck price is: " + productDetails.getPrice());
        }else{

            Log.d(TAG,"No Product Detail" );
        }

        Log.d(TAG, "Query inventory was successful.");

//        updateUi();
//        setWaitScreen(false);
        Log.d(TAG, "Initial inventory query finished; enabling main UI.");
    }
```

The program errors when I try to get "productDetails.getPrice()"  for example.

Any help is appreciated.  This has been a two-day head banger.

TIA

Comment: Did you change something in the SkeuDetails default implementation? getPrice() should return empty String if there is no price.

Comment: I have checked and a Price is available on the Dev Console. I receive the same error for getType() and getTitle().  I did not change anything in the SkuDetails default implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was not calling the listener with the correctly formatted inquire.

I added the code below and passed the information to the listener and my product details are now showing up.

Below is the code I changed:

```
String[] moreSkus = {SKU_ANATVITALSIGNS};
mHelper.queryInventoryAsync(true, Arrays.asList(moreSkus), mGotInventoryListener);
```

That fixed the problem.